# JavaScript RegEx to replace repeat characters of more than 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an string, like `YYYY/MMM/DD` and I want to convert it into YY/MM/DD formart.
In short, I want to replace repeated characters more than 2.

Example 01:-  `YYYY/MMM/DD` -> `YY/MM/DD`
Example 02 :- `MMM/YYYY/DD` -> `MM/YY/DD`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, using back references to find sequences of 3+ the same character and then replacing them with just two:

```
str.replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g, '$1$1')
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use this

```
    var date = new Date();
    var datestr = ('0' + date.getDate()).substr(-2, 2) + '/' + ('0' + date.getMonth()).substr(-2, 2) + '/' + ('0' + date.getFullYear()).substr(-2, 2);
    alert(datestr);
```

Comment: This is not replacing repeated characters in a string, this is generating a date.